# NEST ElasticSearch filter doesn't return all values

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

So I'm trying the following query but I only get ten results. I want all matching results.

```
elasticSearchQuery = (q => q.Filtered(frd => frd
                     .Query(qf => qf.MatchAll())
                     .Filter(f => f.Bool(b =>
                             b.Must(mt =>
                             mt.Term("productType", productTypeId)
                     )))));
```

The MatchAll part doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify number of results. From and size can be set as request parameters, they can also be set within the search body. from defaults to 0, and size defaults to 10.

Comment: But I want them all! And I have no idea how many there possibly are? So then like just set int.MaxValue as Size?

Comment: You have two options, execute count query and fetch all results or iterate over the results using From and Size.

Answer (score 0):

D Volsky is correct, the default size is 10.  You can see this in the documentation here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

The reason for this is that results that appear completely unrelated might be returned even if their score is low.  You might try having your query return 1000 or more results, but applying a min_score to the results.  A min_score may help to ensure your results are still relevant. Documentation for min_score here: 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html